# Rendering to Texture

Tags: render

I'm trying to render to a texture, I can put up a full screen quad but when I render and then use that render target it only shows the background, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Im in directX, here is some code.

```
           m_deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP); //draw a fullscreen quad
m_deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader[6].Get(), nullptr, 0);

m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);
m_deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader[3].Get(), nullptr, 0);

m_deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, m_samplerState.GetAddressOf());
m_deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, srv);
m_deviceContext->Draw(4, 0);
m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_rtv.GetAddressOf(), 0); //render with the render to texture.
m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_rtv.Get(), m_backgroundcolors);



m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);


m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), 0);

m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView.Get(), m_backgroundcolors);

m_deviceContext->VSSetShader(0, 0, 0);

m_deviceContext->GSSetShader(0, 0, 0);

m_deviceContext->PSSetShader(0, 0, 0);

m_deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP); //draw a fullscreen quad
m_deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader[6].Get(), nullptr, 0);

m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);
m_deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader[3].Get(), nullptr, 0);


m_deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, m_samplerState.GetAddressOf());
m_deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, m_srv[0].GetAddressOf());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
aiString texture;
Mat->GetTexture( ..., &texture);
```

The GetTexture-method expects a valid instance of aiString. Then your code shall work as expectrd.